# Appending after an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery in my current project. I have an list of elements with unique ids.  I would like to pick out a particular element and append a new list item after that element.  For example, if I have something like:

```
<ul>
    <li id="one">one</li>
    <li id="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to append `<li id="two">two</li>` after the list item with an id of one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('ul #one').after('<li id="two">two</li>');
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that in the API. Thanks.

Comment: If that solved your problem, Matt would probably appreciate if you marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: You have to wait a little bit before it will let you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the imaginatively named [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method.